# расчитать процент между двумя числами

Tags: php

Добрый день, мне нужно рассчитать разницу в процентах двух чисел, оба могут меняться в большую/меньшую сторону. не могу найти нужную формулу. Пробую разные

```
$a = 10;
$b = 15;
echo 100 * ($a / $b) - 100; // -33.3 b больше в полтора раза а не 1 / 3
$a = 10;
$b = 15;
echo ($b - $a) * 10; // 50 верно, но при попытке увеличить до тысяч результат неверен
echo $a / 100 * $b; - также.
$a = 1500;
$b = 1400;
echo (($b - $a) / $a) * 100; // выдает разные процент при смене чисел
```

Не может быть чтобы ответа не было

Comment: *мне нужно рассчитать разницу в процентах двух чисел* Надеюсь, Вы понимаете, что у задачи в такой постановке всегда ДВА правильных ответа, если числа не равны? Ибо хочешь не хочешь, но одно считается за 100%, а другое - сколько-то... так что начинать надо с выбора числа, которое является "базой". В любом случае если `a` есть 100%, то отличие от него `b` в долях составляет `ABS(1 - b/a)`, а в процентах - домножить результат на сто. И да, оба числа желательно чтобы были положительны (или хотя бы одного знака), а то совсем хрень получится.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = 10, b = 15;
console.log((b / a - 1) * 100);
```

Comment: В php работать не будет :Р

Comment: Будем надеяться, что  добавить $ к переменным  и заменить  console.log на echo Иван сможет:)

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае решение такое:

```
if ($a === $b) {
    echo "А и Б равны\n";
} elseif ($a < $b) {
    $diff = $b - $a;
    $percent = $diff / $b * 100;
    echo "А меньше Б на {$percent}%\n";
} else {
    $diff = $a - $b;
    $percent = $diff / $a * 100;
    echo "Б меньше А на {$percent}%\n";
}
```

1 - определяем бОльшее из двух чисел; 2 - находим разницу; 3 - вычисляем, какой процент эта разница составляет от бОльшего числа.

Дальше можно усложнить понимание, сократив код. Определять без условий max($a, $b), находить разницу между ними без условий через abs($a - $b) и раскрыть скобки в выражениях. Но эт вы лучше сами :)